# CSS not loading from Jade when rendered by Express

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Here's the code for express routing:

```
var express = require('express')
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  path = require('path'),

var app = new express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'jade')

app.use(express.static())
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')))

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index')
})
```

Here's the jade file:

```
html
    head
        title
        link(href='./simple-color-picker.css', rel='stylesheet')

    body
        block scripts 
            script(type='text/javascript' src='../public/bundle.js')
        form(method="post",enctype="multipart/form-data",action="/")
            p
                input(type="text",name="title",placeholder="title")
            p
                input(type="file",name="upl")
            p
                input(type="submit")
```

If I drag the index.html(built from the jade file) it works perfectly in the browser but when running the express file I get 404 errors for the CSS and a P5.js file in my bundle.js. I think I'm supposed to serve them as static files but that gives me the ERR_CONNECTION REFUSED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong route configs, this:

```
app.use(express.static());
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index')
});
```

Must be

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you place your css and js files in public folder like

--public

---simple-color-picker.css

---bundle.js

then

change

```
 link(href='./simple-color-picker.css', rel='stylesheet')
 script(type='text/javascript' src='../public/bundle.js')
```

to

```
 link(href='/simple-color-picker.css', rel='stylesheet')
 script(type='text/javascript' src='/bundle.js')
```